# EventHandler is Null When running MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

So I'm attempting to have shared variables in my WPF app. In doing so I've implemented a `ViewModelController` class to store variables that affect the rest of my app, using an `eventhandler`.

My `ViewModelController` class is as such:

```
    public class ViewModelController
    {

        private DataRowView _SelectedUniverse;

        public MenuViewModel MenuViewModel { get { return new MenuViewModel(this); } }

        public GamePageViewModel GamePageViewModel { get { return new GamePageViewModel(this); } }

        public PlayersViewModel PlayersViewModel { get { return new PlayersViewModel(this); } }

        public event EventHandler UniverseChanged;

        public DataRowView SelectedUniverse
        {
            get { return _SelectedUniverse; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedUniverse = value;
                UniverseChanged.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                Debug.Print("Universe Changed in ViewModelController");
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm testing this on my Menu ViewModel to see if it passes to a another class:

`MenuViewModel`

```
    public class MenuViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        ViewModelController _ViewModelController;
        private DataView _Universes;
        private DataRowView _SelectedUniverse;

        public MenuViewModel(ViewModelController controller)
        {
            _ViewModelController = controller;
            _Universes = Controller.UniverseTableAdapter.GetData().DefaultView;
        }

        public DataView Universes
        {
            get { return _Universes; }
            set
            {
                _Universes = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Universes");
            }
        }

        public DataRowView SelectedUniverse
        {
            get { return _SelectedUniverse; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedUniverse = value;
                Debug.Print("Universe Changed from Menu");
                _ViewModelController.SelectedUniverse = _SelectedUniverse;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedUniverse");
            }
        }
    }
```

`PlayerViewModel` Class

```
public class PlayersViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    private ViewModelController _ViewModelController;

    #region Variables
    private ObservableCollection<Player> _Players = Controller.GetPlayers(0);
    private Player _SelectedPlayer;
    private DataView _Colleges = Controller.CollegeTableAdapter.GetData().DefaultView;
    private DataView _Universes = Controller.UniverseTableAdapter.GetData().DefaultView;

    private long _PlayerID;
    private string _PlayerFirstName;
    private string _PlayerLastName;
    private string _PlayerFullName;
    private DataRowView _SelectedCollege;
    private DataRowView _SelectedUniverse;
    private long _PlayerCollegeID;
    private long _UniverseID;
    private int _PlayerEnteredYear;

    private DataView _RegularSeasonStats = Controller.SeasonView.GetData().DefaultView;
    private DataRowView _SelectedSeason;
    private DataView _PlayoffStats = Controller.PlayoffsView.GetData().DefaultView;
    private DataView _PlayerSchedule = Controller.PlayerScheduleView.GetDataByPersonAndYear(0, 0).DefaultView;
    #endregion 

    public PlayersViewModel(ViewModelController controller)
    {
        _ViewModelController = controller;
        _ViewModelController.UniverseChanged += OnUniverseChanged;
        Debug.Print("PlayerViewModel Constructed");
    }

    public DataRowView SelectedUniverse
    {
        get { return _SelectedUniverse; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedUniverse = value;
            if(_SelectedUniverse != null)
            {
                _UniverseID = _SelectedUniverse.Row.Field<long>("UniverseID");
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedUniverse");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnUniverseChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedUniverse = _ViewModelController.SelectedUniverse;
        Debug.Print("Universe was changed");
    }
}
```

When the `SelectedUniverse` is changed, it sends that variable to the `ViewModelController`, which should invoke the `UniverseChanged` event. However, I'm getting an `Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object`.

I know I'm supposed to instantiate the `EventHandler`, but I'm not seeing a way to instantiate it without a constructor. Could I be going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're forcing to invoke the `UniverseChanged` event but there's no listener to handle it, so the event actually can be null.

You should check if there are listeners before invoke. Like this:

```
public DataRowView SelectedUniverse
{
    get { return _SelectedUniverse; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedUniverse = value;
        UniverseChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        // Or if you're using a C# version< 6:
        // var evtHandlers = UniverseChanged;
        // if(evtHandlers != null) evtHandlers.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        Debug.Print("Universe Changed in ViewModelController");
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your C#<6 code needs to store the delegate in a variable first, then operate on that variable instead of the actual delegate in order to avoid some rare race-conditions.

Comment: @BradleyUffner You're right. Thanks for notice that.

Comment: Example here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/

Comment: So that does help, although it doesn't fire off the `OnUniverseChanged` method in my `PlayersViewModel`.... I added a listener to that didn't I?

Comment: @jDave1984 I'm talking about the error _`Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object`_ you've mentioned. The `PlayersViewModel` class (the only one subscribing the referred event) is never being called (no `get` invocation) in your code (in the example at least).

Comment: And I can't see a reason for you to return a new instance of those objects on every `get`

Comment: Yeah I'm currently in the process of refactoring this. However, the `get` is in my XAML binding, however... apparently not. I may need a better, more efficient way to switch viewmodels and have some shared variables in between

Comment: @jDave1984 So, what can I do to help you? Did my post answer your question?

Comment: It did answer my original question of the Null error, so I'll give you credit for the answer. If you can help me in a chat or email on a better structure I would very much appreciate it

Comment: @jDave1984 [Let's talk in chat, then](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170636/discussion-between-jdave1984-and-diego).